# LayoutInflater Exception using BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, json, baseadapter

My class extends BaseAdapter and I am using Fragment but I am getting **NullPointerException** at this line:

```
  this.myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
```

May I know what is the reason ? Why i am facing this issue ? How can i resolve this ?

**Adapter** code:

```
public class GridViewImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<Wallpaper> _wallPArray;

    private LayoutInflater myInflater;

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Utils utils;
    private ImageLoaderConfiguration config;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;

    public GridViewImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Wallpaper> filePaths) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this._wallPArray = filePaths;


        this.myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity); // getting NPE


        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();        
        utils = new Utils(activity);

        //Create configuration for ImageLoader
        config = utils.ImgLoaderConfiguration();

        // Creates display image options for custom display task
        options = utils.DisplayImgOptions();

        // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
        imageLoader.init(config);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_gridview_image, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.preview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

**Logcat:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:211)
            at com.test.data.GridViewImageAdapter.<init>(GridViewImageAdapter.java:42)
            at com.test.data.PhotosFragment.jsonTaskComplete(PhotosFragment.java:112)
            at com.test.data.PhotosFragment$JsonDownloaderTask.onPostExecute(PhotosFragment.java:149)
            at com.test.data.PhotosFragment$JsonDownloaderTask.onPostExecute(PhotosFragment.java:118)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5061)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: have you checked whether the activity is null or not which you are passing  in `GridViewImageAdapter(....)` method

Comment: use this : convertView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.row_answers, null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May I know what is the reason ? Why i am facing this issue ? How can i
>   resolve this ?

The reason is, `activity` is null. Check that you are instantiating the adapter, when you have a valid `Context`. E.g. inside `onCreate`. Since you are using the Activity only to retrieve the `LayoutInflater` you could also pass only the an instance of `LayoutInflater`

Comment: thanks finally i surrounded my code with try-catch block in onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following thing:

```
this.myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
```

if you are in a fragment, this is the way to get the valid context

Answer (score 0):

if u r using fragment then try this code

```
this.myInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

public GridViewImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList filePaths) {}

use context instead of activity in ur code